# Flatten 3D position to 1D using width, height and length

Tags: c#, 3d, flatten

I want to flatted a 3D position to 1D using width, height and length

I can do it using only width and height using
x + Width * (y + Height * z)
test:
7 + 8 * (7 + 8 * 7) = 511 (expected)

And it works fine, but it misses length

I tried code from the internet but all of them miss length, and chatgpt gave me a broken one

x + width * (y + height * z) + length * width * height * z
test:
7 + 8 * (7 + 8 * 7) + 8 * 8 * 8 * 7 = 4095 (not expected, I want 511)

Comment: @Fildor I think the OP's intention is this: given a 3D array that is layed out sequentially in memory (i.e. in 1D), how to convert (x,y,z) coordinate to an index in the 1D array in memory.

Comment: @wohlstad Haha, you may be right. I was totally thinking "mathematically" ... lol

Comment: What is length? Why do you need length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to index a 3 dimensional room of width `W` x height `H` x length `L` you can index like so:

index i = f(w,h,l) = w * (H*L) + h * L + l

with w in [0..W[, h in [0..H[, l in [0..L[

See this fiddle as an example:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/RDI1RY

```
public static int GetIndex(int x, int y, int z, int W, int H, int L)
{
    //You could do some sanitychecking here ... 
    //if( x < 0 || x >= W ) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(x));
    // ... but the important thing is:
    return z + (y * L) + (x * H * L);
}
```

Output:

```
...
7|7|4 => 508
7|7|5 => 509
7|7|6 => 510
7|7|7 => 511
```

Comment: In the return code you used L 2 times and didnt use W, which of the 2 should be W? I guess the first one since x corresponds to width, y to height and z to length?

Comment: Yes, sorry. W is only used to sanitycheck x's range, H corresponds to y and L to z. So I used z here for the least significant part, which means it goes into the function directly. y is the second most significant part, which means it needs to be scaled by the least significant part's range. And then x as most significant part must scale with the product of all less significant ranges, which is L again multiplied by H. Because when it increases, we need to advance the index by L*H places.

Comment: But wouldn't that make Length = Width, making Width useless, making it a X Y X size box instead of X Y Z?

Comment: No, why would you think that? Let's do an example: We have a box of 3 by 5 by 7. Now if we view that as left-to-right most significant to least significant, we must compute an index i for x,y,z as z + y * 7 + x * 5 * 7. For each x, there are 5*7 indices of y and z. for each y there are 7 indices of z.

Comment: I've changed the code you sent to z + (y * W) + (x * H * L) and now it supports W too

Comment: But that will only be correct if W = H = L. Or at least W = L.

Comment: You can play around with W,H,L in this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dU3Ota to see the effects.

Comment: Thank you, it seems like that was a misunderstanding on my part, under a series of testing both in C# and HLSL it seems like it works just fine, thank you.